# XCode - Mysql two tables and Grouped tableview

Tags: mysql, xcode, uitableview

I have two mysql tables that contain data about appointments ( private, professional ) and the structure is identical. I would like to fetch data of both tables to arrays and display the data grouped by category in a uitableview for the current date.

I know how to display data in a plain uitableview with 1 table but I don't know how to proceed here since i never worked with sections. Most tutorials I find work with static sections which is not what I need.
Please advise.